# jQuery AJAX file upload to WCF web service fails on large data

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, wcf

I am writing part of an application which allows files to be drag/dropped, and uploaded to the web server via ajax.

Here is my jQuery code snippet that uploads the file to the WCF web service:

```
var fileData = JSON.stringify({
    filename: file.name,
    contentType: file.type,
    data: e.target.result
});

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "/site/app.svc/GetFile",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: fileData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    processData: false
});
```

Here is my WCF web service code snippet that gets the file data, and saves it:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
public bool GetFile(string filename, string contentType, string data)
{
    try
    {
        var tokens = data.Split(',');
        File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\" + filename, System.Convert.FromBase64String(tokens[1]));
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This works OK for small files, but when I get to around even 80Kb...it fails with the message

> 413 Request Entity Too Large

...and on occasion

> 500 Internal Server Error

Any ideas on why it fails when it hits a particular size limit? Is this a limitation of the ajax post size, or would it more likely be the WCF service limiting what can and cannot be sent?

Comment: Most probably the 413 comes from limitations of WCF and 500 is because your request exceedes the maximum allowed request size for ASP.NET. All limits can be reconfigured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try sen these property of your config to some big value ? 
    maxBufferPoolSize, 
    maxReceivedMessageSize, 
    maxBufferSize

Comment: Yes, we finally managed to find out that we needed to edit these in the web config to support larger files. Thanks/accepted! :-)